# How to add analytics to an aumented reality site?

Tags: web-applications, google-analytics, analytics, aframe

is it posible to add analytics to a site using this framework https://aframe.io/ ?

I have to implement analytics to an augmented reality site developed with that framework, I was told that I can not use the google analytics tool unless it is easy to implement, but my question here is, is it even posible to implement analytics using that framework?

the a-frame framework uses html tags to add 3d components to the site, so it isn't normal html, that's why I have doubts about how to implement it

this are the things that are required to track

1. track all the pages that the user open
2. track the time that the user stays in the site
3. track which buttons the users click on

Comment: You can use Google Analytics with A-Frame with no issue. An immersive site is no different than a regular 2D site. All the metrics you mentioned: users, session duration, events... that Google Analytics provides will work with A-Frame too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use echoAR instead. Just upload your assets there and use the API to fetch them when you need them. Then in the console, you can see your analytics automatically.

Comment: you were right, it doesn't matter if the site is 2d or 3d or whatever you still can use google analytics